# Show UIImageView in front of UIView

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to show a UIImageView in front of a UIView (for Preview live)?
I try to make a camera based application so when clicking on a button the app take a pic and show it into UIImageView.

Comment: i think u using storyboard. its correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myView addSubview: myImageView]
```

should work fine. if not please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the view programmatically the previous suggestion should do it.  If the views are in a storyboard or XIB and you want to move it to the front, try this:

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:myImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use **[UIKit Peek and Pop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html)** if you are on iOS 9 or above.

Also there is this tutorial: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/3d-touch-peek-and-pop/